# ERROR:The name 'Controls' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export

I am exporting to an Excel file from a GridView, and I get the above error.

```
  protected void ExportExcelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewExportUtil.Export("Issues.csv", this.gvIssues);
    }
```

Which calls:

```
 public class GridViewExportUtil
{
    public static void Export(string fileName, GridView gv, HashSet<string> selectedRows)
    {
    public static void Export(string fileName, GridView gv)
    {
        Table excelTable = new Table();
        excelTable.GridLines = GridLines.Both;


        excelTable.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow);
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gv.Rows)
        {
            excelTable.Rows.Add(gvRow);

        }

        StringWriter wrt = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(wrt);

        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
        Controls.Add(form); // here is where the error is found
        form.Controls.Add(gv);
        form.RenderControl(htw);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + DateTime.Today + ".xls");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(wrt.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

The piece of code:

```
 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
        Controls.Add(form); // here is where the error is found
        form.Controls.Add(gv);
        form.RenderControl(htw);
```

Was put in to try and counter the error: `Control 'cbSelectAll_0' of type 'CheckBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.`

The following also didn't help: `VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control)`: no suitable method found to override

Comment: How is this method called, and why is it static?

Comment: It is called on Button_Click, It is found on `GridViewExportUtil` class

Comment: Can you add this piece of `Button_Click`, or the whole handler, in the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes it is executed as a part of Page's method. There `Controls` would make sense, as `Page.Controls` refers to the collection of controls on the page.

Not sure how did you expect this to work fine inside a static utility method of some other class (according to comments, this method is a part of `GridViewExportUtil` class), but anyway, to fix it just pass instance of the parent control (could be a page) as an additional input:

```
public static void Export(string fileName, GridView gv, System.Web.UI.Control parentControl)
{
    ...
    parentControl.Controls.Add(form);
    ...
}
```

And on the page where you call it make sure to pass the page object:

```
GridViewExportUtil.Export("some file name", GridView1, this);
```

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali, that update confirms what I suspected already, the answer still holds

Comment: cannot convert from 'BugNET.UserControls.DisplayIssues' to 'System.Web.UI.Page'

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali, that means it is a control and not a page. Simple fix, done